# Steal file descriptors from parent process

Tags: android, linux, root, su, pty

I am using an android system and have a slightly broken su: I get a root shell, but stdin/stdout is acting weird: One example being that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> kills all children of the su process. So since su gets all the input before passing it to its children, I don't think there is anything I could do to fix this without killing the su process.

I thought about writing a small c programm that does the following:

1. Find parent su process id and the file descriptors (for example
   /dev/pts/1)
2. Fork new shell process with fd/0,fd/1,fd/2 pointing to
   /dev/pts/1
3. Kill su process

Would this work? Is there maybe an easier way to stop the su binary from "intercepting" stdin/stdout?

Comment: Does android have the `setsid` command?

Comment: Yes it does. I've just tried `setsid -c bash` inside the partially working root shell, but that didn't seem to fix my problem. It seems like both the bad and a new good root shell are connected to the terminal, and the response is based on a race-condition. Also ctrl+c still closes both root shells.